# remote data: result object with different attributes. how to map?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to use jquery-select2 but I return json objects which have a different structure.
I do not have an `id` and a `text` property but `Code` and `Description`.

```
<input type="hidden" id="select2Test" name="select2Test" value=""/>
```

This an my json object:

```
[{"Code":"20900","Description":"LONDON"}]
```

I've found some sample code on the Internet (and read the docs) but I don't seem to be able to make it work.
This is my javascript:

```
$("#select2Test").select2({
    placeholder: "Search City",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    multiple: false,
    quietMillis: 5000,
    id: function (item) { return { id: item.Code }; },
    ajax: {
        url: '/Services/FetchCities',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: function (term, page) { return { city: term }; },
        results: function (data, page) {
           return { results: data };
        }
    },
    // initSelection: function (item, callback) {
    //     var data = { id: item.Code(), text: item.Description() };
    //     callback(data);
    // },
    formatResult: function (item) { return ('<div>' + item.Code + ' - ' + item.Description + '</div>'); },
    formatSelection: function (item) { return (item.Description); },
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
}).on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert($this.val());
});
```

I've mapped my unique key here:

```
id: function (item) { return { id: item.Code }; },
```

formatted my result here:

```
formatResult: function (item) { return ('<div>' + item.Code + ' - ' + item.Description + '</div>'); },
```

and set the selection here:

```
formatSelection: function (item) { return (item.Description); },
```

so far so good. everything seems to work, except when I try to read or post the value I just get an strange result: `[object Object]`.
I guess it has something to do with the results function:

```
results: function (data, page) {
    return { results: data };
}
```

but I am not 100% sure.

**PS: if I change my returned json object using id and text everything works fine but I can't do that cause other parts of my code use a different reference.**

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've found a solution mapping the data object:

```
results: function (data, page) { 
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
           id: item.Code,
           text: item.Description
            };
        })
    };
}
```

with this changes I don't need to set the id property:

```
// id: function (item) { return { id: item.Code }; },
```

and `formatResult` and `formatSelection`

```
formatResult: function (item) { return ('<div>' + item.id + ' - ' + item.text + '</div>'); },
formatSelection: function (item) { return (item.text); },
```

don't need to be changed.

I am wondering if this is the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution mapping the data object:

```
results: function (data, page) { 
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
           id: item.Code,
           text: item.Description
            };
        })
    };
}
```

with this changes I don't need to set the id property:

```
// id: function (item) { return { id: item.Code }; },
```

and `formatResult` and `formatSelection`

```
formatResult: function (item) { return ('<div>' + item.id + ' - ' + item.text + '</div>'); },
formatSelection: function (item) { return (item.text); },
```

don't need to be changed.

Comment: Did you still need to have `data: function (term, page) { return { city: term }; },` in your code once you used the mapping in the `results`?

Comment: Yes, you need that cause I am sending the city param to my action.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem too, and this doesnt work on the latest plugin v4.0.0
so what i did is the following

```
... ,
processResults: function (data) {
    //where data._embedded.people is the array containing all my objects
    data = $.map(data._embedded.people, function (obj) {
            obj.id = obj.id || obj.ID;
            return obj;
    });

    return {
        results: data
    };
},
...
```

i found the answer in the documentation
https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-id

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your question, but if what you need is to map your object to a select 2 compatible object, I would say you can do this:

```
// Usage: select2Map({Code: '123', Description: 'asd'}) => { id: '123', text: 'asd' }
var select2Map = function(object){
  return {id: object.Code, text: object.Description};
}
```

And use this function like this:

```
results: function (data, page) {
  return { results: select2Map(data) };
}
```

Can you try it, I have not tested it.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work. I have updated my question cause I've found a solution. I don't know if it is the best and the fastest one, though.

Comment: ok, that's good, I did not know `data` was a collection of items.